# How to make abbreviations using a function?

Tags: javascript, string

Here is my code, but it does not work.

```js
function makeAbbr(words) {
  var text = '';
  
  words.split(' ');
  
  for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    text += words[i].substr(0, 1)
  }
  
  return text
}

console.log(makeAbbr('java script'))
```

Comment: Expected output?...can I guess `js`?

Comment: `words` doesn't modify the variable in place, it returns the array. You need to assign it.

Comment: `words = words.split(' ')`

Comment: Learn [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs). [Rubber Duck Debug](//rubberduckdebugging.com/) your code.
Please try using the [debugging capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a) of your browser. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) to your advantage. Note that [`substr`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) is deprecated. All you need is `const makeAbbr = (s) => s.split(" ").map(([ x ]) => x).join("");`.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
function makeAbbr(someStr) {
  const words = someStr.split(" ");
  let abbr = "";
  for (const word of words) {
    abbr += word.substring(0,1);
  }
  return abbr;
}
makeAbbr("I love JavaScript!"); // IlJ
```

.split(...) does not mutate the string (and convert it to an array), but returns the array.
Therefore, you have to assign the result to a variable.